# Configuring .NET Users in IIS 6 (ASP.NET 2.0, Win Server 2003)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

Is it possible in IIS 6 to administrate users as in IIS 7 (e.g. as described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731783%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

In IIS7 you can define users within the ASP.NET group with click on .NET users and it automatically creates a ms sql server db in background in the website directory.

So far I didn't found anything about the issue, most forum questions are about how to migrate asp.net sites from IIS6 to IIS7.

Comment: Ok it seems to me that this is a specific IIS 7 feature. Would be glad if someone could confirm that. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Short: No, IIS 6 does not contain the built-in resource for managing users like IIS7+ do.  Have to remember that IIS6 came out well before ASP.NET and especially the membership providers took hold back in the .NET 1.1 and 2.0 days.

However: .NET ships with a [web-based configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Site_Administration_Tool) tool that you can probably use and I would imagine there may be some open source tools over on CodePlex that may provide an even better interface to deal with the ASP.NET Membership Provider.